# How to split a list to certain number of lists

Tags: python, list

```py
with open(path) as file:
    h=file.read().split('\n')
links = list(filter(None, h)) #147 length
chunks = [i.tolist() for i in np.array_split(links, 10) if i.size>0]
```

How can I achieve the same output without using `numpy` or any external library (not pre-installed with python3)?

A reproducible code without any external libraries would be:

```py
links=range(147)
chunks = [i.tolist() for i in np.array_split(links, 10) if i.size>0]
```

The desired output is 10 sub-lists: first 7 sub-list's lengths would be 15 and last 3 sub-list's length would be 14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input:

```
links = list(range(147))
k = 10
```

Iterator solution:

```
from itertools import islice
q, r = divmod(len(links), k)
it = iter(links)
chunks = [list(islice(it, q + (i < r))) for i in range(k)]
```

Walrus solution:

```
q, r = divmod(len(links), k)
i = 0
chunks = [links[i : (i := i + q + (j < r))] for j in range(k)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but this approach should be easily understandable.

```py
import math

L = 147
N = 10
links = range(L)

big_size = math.ceil(L/N)
small_size = math.floor(L/N)
num_big_size = round(N * (L/N - small_size))

chunks = []
ind = 0
for i in range(N):
    if i < num_big_size:
        chunks.append(list(links[ind:ind+big_size]))
        ind += big_size
    else:
        chunks.append(list(links[ind:ind+small_size]))
        ind += small_size
```

Note: this doesn't handle edge cases like some arrays being of size 0. Depending what you want you could filter them out.

**A different approach using padding**

```py
import math

L = 147
N = 10
links = range(L)

big_size = math.ceil(L/N)
small_size = math.floor(L/N)
num_big_size = round(N * (L/N - small_size))

links = list(links)
for i in range((num_big_size+1)*big_size-1, N*big_size, big_size):
    links.insert(i, None)
chunks = [links[i:i+big_size] for i in range(0,N*big_size,big_size)]
chunks = [ [el for el in line if el is not None] for line in chunks]
```

Comment: This works, and I was thinking it would be a 4 line `for` loop or maybe a cool 1 liner

Comment: An alternative approach is to pad the original list out to a size that's an even multiple of N, do the splitting, then strip the padding back out.